# Tensorflow custom gradient: shape of upstream and output gradient

Tags: tensorflow, gradient, loss-function

I am having trouble implementing a custom loss function due to some operations that, although they are tf.functions, have no defined gradient. I was thinking that I could overcome this problem by implementing custom_gradients for each of these operations, but it seems like I am not getting the dimensions/shape of the gradient correctly.
Sadly, this is also hard to debug since, apart from looking at the total gradient of the loss function via GradientTape, there is no way to observe what exactly happens to the gradient throughout its computation (at least as far as I know).
So, imagine a function with f with the @tf.custom_gradient decorator. The function does some operation to the input that changes its shape.

```
@tf.custom_gradient
def f(input):
        output = change_shape(input)

    def grad(upstream):
        return upstream * ???

    return output, grad
```

How can I, e.g., multiply a 1 (something like tf.ones_like(some_shape)) from the right so that the upstream gradient is changed in a way that complies with the change of the tensor shape in the function f?
I have tried many different ways, including just returning upstream as the new gradient, or multiplying a tf.ones_like from the right with the shape of the input (which would be the right way of matrix multiplication according to linear algebra as far as i know). All of those lead to a "None" gradient.

I hope my question is understandable. Sorry for not providing any specific code, I am on a travel right now and lack the ressources to do so.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In TensorFlow, custom gradients allow you to define your own gradient functions for a custom operation. When implementing a custom gradient, it's important to understand the shapes of the upstream gradient (gradients with respect to the output of your custom operation) and the output gradient (gradients with respect to the inputs of your custom operation).

The general form of a custom gradient function in TensorFlow looks like this:

```py
@tf.custom_gradient
def custom_op(x):
    # Forward pass logic
    
    def grad(dy):
        # Backward pass logic
        # Compute gradients with respect to x based on dy (upstream gradient)
        return dx  # Return the gradient with respect to x
    
    return y, grad
```

Here:

- `x` is the input to your custom operation.
- `y` is the output of your custom operation.
- `dy` is the upstream gradient, i.e., the gradient with respect to `y`.

Now, let's discuss the shapes of the upstream gradient (`dy`) and the output gradient (`dx`).

1. **Upstream Gradient (`dy`):**

   - The shape of `dy` is the same as the shape of the output `y`. It represents the gradient of the loss with respect to the output of your custom operation.
2. **Output Gradient (`dx`):**

   - The shape of `dx` should be the same as the shape of the input `x`. It represents the gradient of the loss with respect to the input of your custom operation.

Here's a more concrete example:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

@tf.custom_gradient
def custom_op(x):
    # Forward pass logic
    y = x * x
    
    def grad(dy):
        # Backward pass logic
        dx = 2 * x * dy  # Gradient with respect to x
        return dx
    
    return y, grad

# Example usage
x = tf.constant([1.0, 2.0, 3.0], dtype=tf.float32)

with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    y = custom_op(x)

grad_x = tape.gradient(y, x)

print("Input x:", x.numpy())
print("Output y:", y.numpy())
print("Gradient with respect to x:", grad_x.numpy())
```

In this example, the `custom_op` computes the square of the input `x`. The custom gradient function computes the gradient with respect to `x`, which is `2 * x`. The shapes of `dy` and `dx` align with the rules mentioned earlier.

Comment: Thanks for answering this quickly! Sadly, when I run your code, it gives grad_x=None. This was my problem before. Is this problem only on my end or in your code?

Comment: This answer looks suspiciously like an AI-generated answer, but okay. To get the gradients, either add `tape.watch(x)` inside `with tf.GradientTape() as tape:`, or change `x = tf.constant(...)` to `x = tf.Variable(...)`.